# Redirect to different page depending on host - Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

I have folowing situation:
I have installed Oracle Apex with ORDS on Tomcat and trying to put two applications on different domains.
Here is mu settings:

```
<Host name="domainOne.me"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        
            <Alias>www.domainOne.me</Alias>
            <Alias>domainOne.me</Alias>
    
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="subvencije_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
  <Host name="domainTwo.me"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  
            <Alias>www.domainTwo.me</Alias>
            <Alias>domainTwo.me</Alias>

   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="inovacije_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

Now I need to have a rewrite that will redirect me to different pages depending on host, like this:

- IF domain**One**.me go to domainOne.me/ords/f?p=**111**
- IF domain**Two**.me  go to domainTwo.me/ords/f?p=**222**

**NOTE:** Both apps are in the same appBase (ORDS) and proxy in front of the system is not an option.

Comment: There are many different ways to cause a redirect: a `RewriteValve`, a JSP page, a JSP/JSTL page, a servlet... Which one did you try? Can you add the code/configuration?

Comment: Hi, curentry i am using code in ROOT/Index.JSP with directive: <% response.sendRedirect("https://domainOne.me/ords/f?p=111"); %>